# OpenCV VideoCapture.open() keep changing indexes

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, video-capture, raspberry-pi2, highgui

I'm trying to open my usb camera on my Raspberry Pi using the following code:

```
VideoCapture capture;
capture.open(0);
```

The code can work perfectly one time but after running it again later I get:

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: index 0 is not correct!
```

without touching the camera or the code! Sometimes changing to `capture.open(1);` solves it but sometimes not. I read somewhere you can use `(-1)` and it will use the first camera it finds but that didn't work either.

Comment: What USB camera have you got?

Comment: [Logitech QuickCam Communicate STX](http://support.logitech.com/product/quickcam-communicate-stx). Do you think it got something to do with the camera? It is very old...

Comment: What output do you get if you execute `lsusb -t`

Comment: I tried a newer logitech camera and I get the same problem. here is what I get with `lsusb -t`:

Comment: `pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop/Track $ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=smsc95xx, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M`

Comment: `|__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 1, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 2, Class=audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 3, Class=audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=rt73usb, 480M`